# conditional styling without 'else' in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a component that is being used by many pages:

```
<input 

  ng-style="{$ctrl.page0 ? 'border-color:blue' : ''}" 
  
  class="form-control" 
  type="text" 
  ng-change="$ctrl.dateChange()" 

/>

  <button ng-click="$ctrl.open()">Continue</button>
```

I want to use something like this:

```
ng-style="{$ctrl.page0 ? 'border-color:blue' : ''}"
ng-style="{$ctrl.page1 ? 'border-color:red' : ''}"
ng-style="{$ctrl.page2 ? 'border-color:yellow' : ''}"
```

But because of the "else", it won't work

What is the syntax to just use:

```
ng-style="{$ctrl.page0 ? 'border-color:blue'}"
```

Comment: "But because of the "else", it won't work" What did you mean by **it won't work**? You can use default color in else part. `ng-style="{$ctrl.page0 ? 'border-color:blue' : 'border-color:black'}"`

Comment: The default color overrides the rest of the code. If it is 'page1', it should be red. But it will give either ' ' or 'black'.

Answer (score 0):

According to the given details, Try below code.

```
    ng-style="{'border-color': $ctrl.page0 ? 'blue' : 
               ($ctrl.page1 ? 'red' : ($ctrl.page2 ? 'yellow' : '')) }"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
ng-style="$ctrl.page0 ? {border-color:'blue'} : {}"
```